# SetInterval continues sending requests without stopping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, setinterval

```
$("#servers li a").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    var server = $('li.active a').text();
    $("#appname").text(server);
    var jsonLoader = setInterval(function() {
        loadJason();
    }, 1000);
    var clearStuff = function() {
      clearInterval(jasonLoader);
    }
    function loadJason() {
        $.getJSON(('http://localhost:4567/' + server), function(data) {
            $(".box-requests").text(data.requests);
            $(".box-idle-workers").text(data.idle_workers);
            $(".box-requests-per-second").text(data.requests_per_second);
            $(".box-cpu").text(data.cpu);
            $(".box-load-average").text(data.load_average);
            $(".box-size-per-req").text(data.size_per_request);
            $(".box-title").text(data.size_title);
        });
    }
});
```

In above code which when 'li' item is clicked, it sends a JSON request to the server every second, with 'li' inner text, like localhost:4567/'innertext of li'. When I click on another li item it is supposed to send a request for another li item, which it does, But does not stop sending a request for the previous item. How to I stop the previous interval.

Comment: clearInterval(jasonLoader); should be clearInterval(jsonLoader);

Comment: well, you don't ever seem to `clearInterval` - so, that's a thing

Comment: I still have same problem, sorry about that jason hahah. Why am i not doing clearInterval. Please explain me. Thank you

Comment: Because you are never calling `clearStuff`.